# Using FFMPEG with Audio and Video side by side

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, mp3

Say I have 3 video files and 2 audio files: `v1.mp4`, `v2.mp4`, `v3.mp4`, `a2.mp3`, `a1.mp3`.

Normally one wants to "overlay" the audio onto the video.

What if one really wants the following;

- v1 plays, no audio
- a1 plays audio, no video
- v2 plays, no audio
- a2 plays audio, no video
- v3 plays video, no audio

All combined in one mp4. My attempts have failed miserably, with either the audio combining onto the video, corrupted video, or long encoding times.

In the end I want to have these video streams concatenated together with "intertitial" parts that are blank and have no video. I have tried

- Complex filter with `color=black` pieces concatenated. Works but reencodes and is very slow

  ```
  ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -filter_complex "
  color=black:s=1280x720:d=5[s1];
  color=black:s=1280x720:d=10[s2];
  color=black:s=1280x720:d=15[s3];
  [0:v][s1][1:v][s2][2:v][s3]concat=n=6:v=1:a=0[aout]" -map [aout] -y output.mp4
  ```
- Create a bunch of `color=black` mp4 from scratch and use a merge file. Video turns green and complains timeframes.

  ```
  ffmpeg -t 60 -s 640x480 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 25 -i /dev/zero empty.mpeg
  ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy test.mp4
  ```

(list is basically `1.mp4`, `empty.mp4`, `2.mp4`, `empty.mp4`, `3.mp4`)

- Create a bunch of mp3's with just silence and merge them together.

  ```
  ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy test.mp4
  ```

(but the mylist contains `silence.mp3` files instead of an `empty.mp4` between each)

Comment: What video should be displayed for the audio-only inputs? Black video, some sort of visualization filter, etc? You need to show the complete console output of `ffmpeg -i v1.mp4 -i v2.mp4 -i v3.mp4 -i a2.mp4 -i a1.mp3`

Comment: clarified above

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to achieve. You can't have "no video"  during the audio only sections; you need some sort of video placeholder/filler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below command does it. It creates three silence audio and two black video streams from scratch and then merge them with other streams by two `concat` filters. (with assuming that all your inputs are 15 seconds duration).

`ffmpeg -t 15 -f lavfi -i anullsrc -i a1.mp3 -t 15 -f lavfi -i anullsrc -i a2.mp3 -t 15 -f lavfi -i anullsrc -i v1.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=black:s=1280x720:r=25:d=15 -i v2.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=black:s=1280x720:r=25:d=15 -i v3.mp4 -filter_complex [0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a]concat=n=5:v=0:a=1[aud];[5:v][6:v][7:v][8:v][9:v]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0[vid] -c:v libx264 -c:a libmp3lame -map [vid] -map [aud] output.mp4`

Comment: You can skip the multiple anullsrc and color generators and create just one of each. Source input pads can be reused.

Comment: @Mulvya but assumed that their duration may differ, i can't come up with one stream for each